# Why does acetate ion react with water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, ions

When NaCl is added to water, it dissociates into $\rm{Na^+}$ and $\rm{Cl^-}$. The newly formed $\rm{Na^+}$ and $\rm{Cl^-}$ do not react with water.

When $\rm{CH_3COONa}$ (sodium acetate) is added to water, it dissociates into $\rm{CH_3COO^-}$ and $\rm{Na^+}$. The newly formed $\rm{CH_3COO^-}$ reacts with water to form $\rm{CH_3COOH}$ and $\rm{OH^-}$ ions.

Why is it that $\rm{Cl^-}$ does not react with water, but $\rm{CH_3COO^-}$ reacts with water?

Comment: Search for concept of strong and weak acids.

Comment: Chloride ion is stable enough to exist on its own, acetate not so much and thus tries to grab $\ce{H+}$ from water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Bronsted-Lowry Acid-Base theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%B8nsted%E2%80%93Lowry_acid%E2%80%93base_theory), *stronger acids* have *weaker conjugate bases* and vice-versa.

$\ce{HCl}$, being a strong acid in water, it's conjugate base i.e $\ce{Cl-}$ is weak or it is *more stable*. Although it reacts with $\ce{H2O}$ but to a very less extent. Whereas in the case of $\ce{CH3COOH}$, it being a weak acid, it's conjugate base is a *strong* base. So, it reacts with water and forms *relatively more stable* $\ce{CH3COOH}$.

The degree of hydrolysis, $\mathrm{h}$ of a salt of weak acid and strong base is approximately given by
$\mathrm{h}$=$\sqrt{k_w/Ck_a}$.

If you substitute the $\mathrm{k_a}$ value for $\ce{CH3COOH}$ ( $\mathrm{k_a}$=$\pu{1.8E-5}$) for a $\mathrm{0.1M}$ solution of $\ce{CH3COONa}$, which yields $\mathrm{h=}$ $\pu{7.45E-4}$ where as for $\mathrm{0.1M}$ $\ce{NaCl}$ (although approximate) $\mathrm{h\approx}$$\pu{ 10^-10}$, which is  negligible when compared to degree of hydrolysis of $\ce{CH3COONa}$.

Comment: I agree that Cl- ion is stable because it has octet. Can we give a reason for the lesser stability of CH3COO- ion?

Comment: @NikhilKumar Carbon isn't enough electronegative to hold the negative charge